# Where in the players handbook do you find what dice you roll for spell damage for the socerer

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Me and my DM were trying to find where it's says what dice you roll for damage for differnt spells

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is either trolling, or makes no sense as asked. Have you not read the rulebook to even this extent? One of the reasons this site exists is to help with difficult interpretations of the rules where they are unclear. The information you are asking for is unambiguously explicit throughout the text.

Comment: Unless they don't understand that 4d6 means four six-sided dice. OP, if you're brand new to the game, the shorthand is: [amount] of [type of die], and it's written as follows: d20 = One twenty-sided die. 2d6 = Two six-sided dice. 4d8 = Four eight-sided dice. So a spell that deals 12d10 damage means you roll twelve ten-sided dice for damage.

Comment: Yes i am new to tabletop games so you don't have to be rude about a question that you didn't have to look at and let people help other people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells you in each spell description.